# Erro "Cannot read property 'x' of undefined" Raphael.js

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte erro ao utilizar o browser:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

e não me apresenta nada. Utilizando o jsfiddle funcionar perfeitamente e não tenho erro, utilizando o mesmo código. Penso que será problema da biblioteca.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="raphael.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
```

Exemplo no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tttxfvcu/16/)

Comment: breakpoints, breakpoints everywhere...

Comment: No meu caso, hoje, tive este erro após um conjunto de dados vazio e/ou com erro foi enviado ao gráfico.
Exemplo: O usuário acessando o sistema não tem permissão para requisitar os dados no banco e exibir para o gráfico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem dois problemas;

1. Você adicionou duas vezes o Raphal.js

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="raphael.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
   ```

   Ou use a versão de produção ou o cdn.
2. Eu testei ontem e não vi este erro `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined` até chamar o construtor para gerar um SVG, o que acontece é que a página não havia terminado de carregar antes de executar o Raphal.js, você pode fazer de duas maneiras:

   - Usando `window.onload`:

     ```
     window.onload = function() {
         var paper = Raphael("canvas", 640, 480);
             paper.clear();
             paper.circle(320, 240, 60);
     };
     ```
   - Usando `jQuery.ready`:

     ```
     $(function() {
         var paper = Raphael("canvas", 640, 480);
             paper.clear();
             paper.circle(320, 240, 60);
     });
     ```

Exemplo do código html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo simples</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var paper = Raphael("canvas", 640, 480);
            paper.clear();
            paper.circle(320, 240, 60);
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```